# What is the preferred way to get code to execute in a WPF GUI thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, task-parallel-library

I have a main thread that contains my WPF GUI and one or more background threads that occassionally need to execute code in the main thread asynchronously (e.g. a status update in the GUI).

There are two ways (that I know of, maybe more) to accomplish this:

1. by scheduling a task using the `TaskScheduler` from the target thread's synchronization context, and
2. by invoking a delegate using the `Dispatcher` from the target thread.

In code:

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

Action mainAction = () => MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Hello from thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
Action backgroundAction;

// Execute in main thread directly (for verifiying the thread ID)
mainAction();

// Execute in main thread via TaskScheduler
var taskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
backgroundAction = () => Task.Factory.StartNew(mainAction, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, taskScheduler);
Task.Factory.StartNew(backgroundAction);

// Execute in main thread via Dispatcher
var dispatcher = System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
backgroundAction = () => dispatcher.BeginInvoke(mainAction);
Task.Factory.StartNew(backgroundAction);
```

I like the TPL-based version, because I already use TPL a lot and it provides me with a lot of flexibility, e.g. by waiting on the task or chaining it with other tasks. However, in most examples of WPF code I have seen so far, the Dispatcher variant was used.

Assuming I didn't need any of that flexibility and only wanted to execute some code in the target thread, what are the reasons one would prefer one way over the other? Are there any performance implications?

Comment: +1. I didn't know the `FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` method even existed!

Comment: i would consider using `Tasks` for one-time/one-off async processing.  however, using `Dispatcher.Invoke` seems necessary for a background thread which runs the length of the application and periodically retrieves information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I highly recommend that you read the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=19957) document. This will allow you to structure your APIs to be ready when `async` and `await` hit the streets.

I used to use `TaskScheduler` to queue updates, similar to your solution ([blog post](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2010/06/reporting-progress-from-tasks.html)), but I no longer recommend that approach.

The TAP document has a simple solution that solves the problem more elegantly: if a background operation wants to issue progress reports, then it takes an argument of type `IProgress<T>`:

```
public interface IProgress<in T> { void Report(T value); }
```

It's then relatively simple to provide a basic implementation:

```
public sealed class EventProgress<T> : IProgress<T>
{
  private readonly SynchronizationContext syncContext;

  public EventProgress()
  {
    this.syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current ?? new SynchronizationContext();
  }

  public event Action<T> Progress;

  void IProgress<T>.Report(T value)
  {
    this.syncContext.Post(_ =>
    {
      if (this.Progress != null)
        this.Progress(value);
    }, null);
  }
}
```

(`SynchronizationContext.Current` is essentially `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` without the need for actual `Task`s).

The Async CTP contains `IProgress<T>` and a `Progress<T>` type that is similar to the `EventProgress<T>` above (but more performant). If you don't want to install CTP-level stuff, then you can just use the types above.

To summarize, there are really four options:

1. `IProgress<T>` - this is the way asynchronous code in the future will be written. It also forces you to separate your *background operation logic* from your *UI/ViewModel update code*, which is a Good Thing.
2. `TaskScheduler` - not a bad approach; it's what I used for a long time before switching to `IProgress<T>`. It doesn't force the UI/ViewModel update code out of the background operation logic, though.
3. `SynchronizationContext` - same advantages and disadvantages to `TaskScheduler`, via [a lesser-known API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx).
4. `Dispatcher` - really can **not** recommend this! Consider background operations updating a ViewModel - so there's nothing UI-specific in the progress update code. In this case, using `Dispatcher` just tied your ViewModel to your UI platform. Nasty.

P.S. If you do choose to use the Async CTP, then I have a few additional `IProgress<T>` implementations in my [Nito.AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/), including one (`PropertyProgress`) that sends the progress reports through `INotifyPropertyChanged` (after switching back to the UI thread via `SynchronizationContext`).

Comment: +1 thanks for the link to the TAP document. Lots of really useful information there. Can't wait for async to ship.

Comment: It's possible to use the Async CTP in production today. I find it very stable, as long as you do not use complex `await` expressions (i.e., just use statements like `var result = await DoMyStuffAsync();`). Normally I'm very conservative and would never use CTP-level stuff, but the Async CTP is well-baked.

Comment: The supplied code isn't thread-safe - there's a race condition in EventProgress<T>. Due to the "new SynchronizationContext", the IProgress<T>.Report method can be called on a thread different than the object's consumer. The consumer can attach or detatch a handler to the Progress event at the same time the event is being raised - the "if (this.Progress != null)" could succeed while the next line of code will throw a NullReferenceException. Great suggestion on the TAP pattern though, it's useful even for fully private/encapsulated async code.

Comment: @ShadowChaser: You are correct; the `EventProgress<T>` isn't threadsafe unless it's used while there's a WinForms/WPF/ASP.NET/SL `SynchronizationContext`. The Async CTP's implementation has a similar problem (though it would invoke an unsubscribed handler rather than cause `NullReferenceException`).

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the `Dispatcher` for any small UI operations, and only use Tasks if a lot of heavy processing is involved. I also use TPL for all background tasks that are not UI-related.

You can use the `Dispatcher` to run tasks at different [Dispatcher Priorities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx), which is often useful when working with the UI, however I find it still locks up the UI thread if there is a lot of heavy processing involved in the background task, which is why I don't use it for large tasks.

Answer (score -1):

I use task based for all heavy operations, but if I need to update the GUI I use the dispatcher otherwise you'll get cross threading exceptions. As far as I'm aware you have to use the dispatcher to update the GUI

update: pete brown covers it well in his blog post http://10rem.net/blog/2010/04/23/essential-silverlight-and-wpf-skills-the-ui-thread-dispatchers-background-workers-and-async-network-programming

Comment: Are you sure you can't use TPL to execute something in the WPF thread? [This sample from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997394.aspx) (which prompted my question) suggests otherwise.

Comment: apologies, properly looking at the msdn pages highlight how that method works. The cost of starting tasks would still make me use the dispatcher for quick ui updates. I would like to see a performance comparison of the two methods