# WPF: Serialport Communication using TAP

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port

I might be completely out in the woods on this one, but. Since TAP (Task-based Asynchronous Pattern, [see this thread, to learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068931/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-get-code-to-execute-in-a-wpf-gui-thread)) separates background operation logic from your UI/ViewModel update code, it would be good to do so when communicating with a serialport.

However, the serialport uses EAP (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152938%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or at I believe so.

So my question is essentially, can TAP be used with a serialport, and should it?

//Rikard

ps. If someone could create TAP/EAP/APM tags (or simple an Asynchronous-Patterns tag), so this qeustion can be properly tagged, I would be most grateful (I lack the rep for it) .ds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we know that TAP is good for heavy **computational operations in memory**, and bad for IO-bound operations, and communicating via Serial Ports is an **IO-bound operation**.

Hence, I don't think it's a good idea to change from EAP to TAP. Because:

For instance, your code mounts a task, which sends some data to a COM port. At the other end, a device will pick up that data to process, and the time required to process the data may be several seconds. During that time, would you hold up the task, hence the thread, several seconds before releasing it back to the processor? It would be really inefficient, IMHO.

PS: Could you reveal what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My goal was is to create a good design for communication over serial port within the gui. In this case the serial port would be sending packages of about 150 bytes of data, with a frequency of 100 Hz, the processing of that data should not take very long (less than a second). The data will be displayed as a graph in the gui, but the gui is not required to update at the same speed, even thou it would be nice. 

I do however agree with you not to use TAP, thus marking this as a correct answer.